# not using nodes in laravel

Tags: laravel, node-modules

**Is that possible to completely remove `node_modules` folder from laravel app and not using it?**

My app doesn't require any `npm packages` and I'm **not using** `echo` or `pusher` or any other API's that requires `npm packages`, then

> Is it OK to remove this unnecessary folder in my app or somehow laravel
>   needs it to work?

Comment: If your project doesn't require node packages then you can remove it, it's not necessary to run Laravel project. But if you're using `VueJS`, or `NodeJS` then you need it.

Comment: @HirenGohel but it won't re-download if later on i update my laravel with composer right?

Comment: `composer update` not download node packages, it only installs packages in `vendor` folder, `node_modules` is different which includes node packages.

Comment: just double check :) thank you.

Comment: No problem, happy to help you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your project doesn't require node packages then you can remove it, it's not necessary to run Laravel project. But if you're using VueJS, or NodeJS then you need it.

`composer update` not download `node packages`, it only installs packages in `vendor` folder, `node_modules` is different which includes node packages.

If you want to install node packages, then use `npm install` command to install it again.

Hope this will helps you!

Answer (score 1):

It is safe to remove the folder. The normal workflow would be to compile all CSS and JS files before deployment and copy them to the `public/` directory, rendering the `node_modules/` obsolete for deployment.

If anything breaks after you removed it, you can still bring it back with `npm install`.

Comment: So if I remove it and later on let say I update my laravel by `composer update` command does it download `node_modules` again? is there any other code that I should remove to avoid re-downloading this folder?

Comment: You can remove the `package.json` if you want. It contains all the packages downloaded to `node_modules` (which only happens if you run `npm install´ or `yarn install` if you use `yarn`). But I'd advise you to not delete it as you may need it further down the road. Pulling everything back together could be quite annoying then.